# Random number array bounded by values in second array

Tags: c++, arrays, random, vector, boundary

Could someone please point me to a good explanation of how this might be accomplished?

For example, let's say I have an array a[j] initialized to the values {3, 4, 5}.  I want to build a second array filled with random numbers bounded below by zero and above by the values in the first array.  So b[i] would be initialized to a random number in the following ranges: {0-3, 0-4, 0-5}

What is a good way of achieving this in C++?

Answer (score 1):

If your system has [`arc4random(3)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/arc4random.3?query=arc4random&sec=3) and friends (and it probably does), it's really easy:

```
int a[3] = {3, 4, 5};
int b[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    b[i] = arc4random_uniform(a[i] + 1);
}
```

From the manual page linked above:

> **`arc4random_uniform()`** will return a single 32-bit value, uniformly distributed but less than *upper_bound*.

Answer (score 0):

The most common function in c++ is the function [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)  which generates a random numer between 0 and RAND_MAX which is defined in cstdlib. That is why you need to use the modulo operation, in your case it would be:

```html
b[i] = rand() % (a[i]+1)
```

Comment: Watch out for [modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) if that might be a problem for your program.